# pressing a letter fires combobox's selectedindexchanged and selectedvaluechanged event?

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindexchanged

There are lots of values in my combobox and they are ordered by alphabetically. When I press a letter to select a value that I want selectedindexchanged and selectedvaluechanged events are fired but I don't want this. Actually I didn't select the value yet. I am trying to reach the value that I want to select. Why is this? How can we prevent this?

```
AUDI
BMW
CITROEN
D...
E...
MERCEDES -> To select this. pressing M fires events???
OPEL
VOLVO
```

Comment: That's what it's designed to do.  When you type, it selects the next matching value (String matching).  What are you expecting it to do then?

Comment: you can use the mouse to prevent it

Comment: it may not be elegant, but perhaps use .LostFocus event instead so that it fires when the control loses it's focus http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx

Comment: @DonBoitnott I don't want to prevent string matching I want to prevent event firing while searching for the value because I didn't select the value yet.

Comment: @V4Vendetta are u serious? what if user press a letter :) do u warn user "only use mouse"?

Comment: couldn't find LostFocus event @Tanner

Comment: But the two are linked.  The selection _is_ the goal, the string matching is the means to that end.  To separate the two is why I question your goal.

Answer (score 1):

In your SelectionChanged event handler, you can handle this by setting e.Handled = true when your ComboBox popup is open. If the popup is closed, you can continue the actual steps you want to execute in your SelectionChanged event.

Or else you could make your own custom control that inherits from ComboBox. In the constructor for that class, add an event handler for SelectionChanged and mark the event as handled by setting e.Handled = true when your popup is open. You may have to play around with which events you're subscribing to/marking as handled in your custom control to get things behaving exactly the way you want.

Note: You can check whether the combobox popup is opened or not by handling the DropDown and DropDownClosed event. :-)

Comment: You aren't wrong.  But you are premature.  This question provides no indication as to what OP expects to have happen.  In fact, it sounds like, "Make this combbox behave _not_ like a combobox should.".

Comment: you can type characters to make a selection in a combobox without having it open

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create new user control or handle this in the event handler, you can use AutoCompleteSource property of combo box. This will raise the SelectedIndexChanged when the user completed his selection by using enter button or control lost the focus or user selects the item using mouse click. For achieve this, set the following properties to the combo box.

```
this.comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
List<string> testString = new List<string>{"abcd", "acde", "adef", "bcde", "bdef", "befg", "cdef", "defg", "cfgh"};
this.comboBox.DataSource = testString;
this.comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += this.ComboBoxOnSelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: @Tanner - If we set AutoCompleSource and AutoCompleteMode property, the combo box will internally handle this problem and gives the desired result.

Comment: @petcirajan no still events are fired after pressing a letter

Comment: @cihata87 : For me combobox is working as expected after these changes. I created one test application and shared it in skydrive.. could you please look into it. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=50299BF79D1E3164!114&authkey=!ANBNvhId7KVm4Bk

Answer (score 0):

selected index changes if you choose something
or turns -1 if the current text is not a item from its list.
which can be a result of changing the text

value change basically fires because text changed no matter if its in the list or not.

Its not exactly clear to me what you want to do; but maybe you want to combine the behaviour, so only fall trough your code; pseudo code like this:

```
 inside your value changedevent()
  {
   // first you might put in some text reformating code here
   // so for example you might replace spaces for '-' or so..
   // or if one presses M,(and text length =1
   // the list of elements in the control 
   // could be filtered on items starting with an M
   // by using a Linq query or so on a list or array.


   If (yourcombobox.selectedindex > -1) {// fire my code as now we're sure its an existing element}
  }
```